# Where does $f_n(x)=n^2x^n$ converge $?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let  ${\{f_n\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$  be  the  sequence  of  functions on  $\mathbb R$  defined  by  $$f_n(x)=n^2x^n.$$ Let $A$  be  the  set of all  points  $a$  in  $\mathbb R$  such  that the  sequence  ${\{f_n(a)\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$  converges . Then ,

$$
\begin{align}
\text A.A&=\{0\}.\\
\text B.A&=[0,1).\\
\text C.A&=\mathbb R\backslash \{-1,1\}.\\
\text D.A&=(-1,1).\\
\end{align}
$$

Now  $f_n$  is  product  of  two  sequences,where $n^2$  is  *unbounded*  . So if $x^n$  tends to $0$  then the product sequence of course converges . Now  for $$x\in (-1,1);\\|x|\lt 1$$ and so $x^n \rightarrow 0.$

So , I selected the option $D$ . Was  I correct $?$

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: @user80631 Check my edit, you may make your questions look nicer that way.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : thanks.